# Tracking pixel in Outlook 2007

Tags: email, google-analytics, outlook, html-email

i have problem with tracking pixel in mso, when i send my campain to gmail it shows and track correctly, but in mso it doesn't show(shows like red x). I found some topics here, but there isn't solution. Every topic say to set mso to force images. That isn't solution for me. I can't manage settings off all target clients. Here is code of pixel.

```
<img src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=XXX&cid=XXX&t=event&ec=XXX&ea=open&cs=newsletter&cn=XXX&cm=email"/>
```

Is here any solution for this?

Comment: There is not, because that is code injection. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i'm trying to do this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/email
but outlook blocked it so its useless for me now..

Answer (score 2):

Outlook does not download remote images until the user explicitly tells Outlook it is OK to download them. This is done on purpose to protect the user from the tracking software.

There is nothing you can do. If there were a way, that would be a bug in Outlook.